# Python the Hard Way ex48

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, automated-tests

I'm having trouble getting the code below to test correctly. The test_errors() function isn't working correctly, but I feel like I've set up my code right. Line 25 is what I thought would work, but I'm not having any luck.

Line25:

```
elif i not in direction or verb or stop or noun:
   scan_result = scan_result + [('error', i)]
```

Whole Code:

```
direction = ('north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'back')
verb = ('go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat')
stop = ('the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it')
noun = ('door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet')
lexicon = {direction: 'direction',
       verb: 'verb',
       stop: 'stop',
       noun: 'noun',
       }


def scan(user_input):
    words = user_input.split()
    scan_result = []
    try:
        for i in words:
            if i.isdigit():
                scan_result = scan_result + [('number', int(i))]
            elif i.lower() in direction or verb or stop or noun:
                for j in lexicon:
                    for k in j:
                        if i.lower() == k:
                            scan_result = scan_result + [(lexicon[j], i)]
            elif i not in direction or verb or stop or noun:
                scan_result = scan_result + [('error', i)]
        return scan_result
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

test_error Function:

```
def test_errors():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("ASDFADFASDF"), [('error', 'ASDFADFASDF')])
    result = lexicon.scan("bear IAS princess")
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear')
                          ('error', 'IAS'),
                          ('noun', 'princess')])
```

Comment: Please please please: [make a relevant title](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not LPTHW support forums.

Comment: I ran your code, by executing `print scan("go in the door")` and it seems to return a list of tuples that have been parsed as you created. When I provided bad input (anything not in the word list), those words were not included in the result. i.e. "bear IAS princess" => [('noun', 'bear'), ('noun', 'princess')]

Comment: Juanpa, definitely will try in the future. Didn't really know how describe problem.

Sunny, yes that's what I'm having issues with. If there is an error it just passes through the scan silently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your code is not line 25 but line 20. Simply checking for a variable will return True unless the variable is `None` or Falsey. Thus when you do `if verb`, if `verb` is set to a tuple, it will evaluate to `True`. Since your first `elif` evaluates to `True`, the block gets executed and the code continues on outside the if..elif..else without evaluating the second `elif` i.e. the 3rd condition, which suffers from the same problem as the first `elif`. This is python tries to find a True condition and as soon as it finds one, it stops checking for any other conditions.

You want to check if the word is either in `direction` or `verb` or `stop` or `noun`. Sadly, the `either..or` pattern doesn't exist in Python.

The correct and pythonic way to check would be the following:

`elif i.lower() in direction + verb + stop + noun:
       ...
   elif i not in direction + verb + stop + noun:
       ...`

Also your `test_errors` function is slightly incorrect. `lexicon` is a `dict` while `scan` is a function and the two are separate, so you can't call `lexicon.scan()`. It should be simply `scan()`.

`assert_equal(scan("ASDFADFASDF"), [('error', 'ASDFADFASDF')])`

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. Plenty of objects are falsey that are not `None`, including an empty tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, this seems to be the issue I'm having. What is weird here is that the first elif seems to work correctly. maybe because the isdigit() function can evaluate false since it looks at whether the tuple is a number or not.

I've tried nesting the second elif under the first elif, but end up having the same issue. The statement just gets evaluated as true. I'll do some troubleshooting now that I know why it is failing to find a solution.
The lexicon.scan function, that is from me being a rookie. The scan function is in a file called lexicon.py, whoops

Answer (score 4):

Change Line 24 to concatenate all 4 tuples into a single tuple:

```
elif i not in direction + verb + stop + noun:
```

You can store all 4 tuples into a single variable if need be, but it should do the trick to check if it exists in any of them.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working either. I believe it is due to the mechanism varagrawal explains further below. the other elif statement in line 20 is being evaluated as true because there is a value and ignoring the elif statement on line 25.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the guilty line by the following but you need to replace the two  elif statements,

Testing verb, stop and noun will always be True since you declare them as tuple, and they contain values (the `or` keyword begin a new expression, it's not adding the groups of words)

```
elif (i not in direction  
    or i not in verb 
    or i not in stop
    or i not in noun):
```

Also you should declared this groups of word as sets, it's better for "in test"

Comment: Tried this, doesn't seem to quite work I get errors because I cannot call a tuple. I do want these to be tuples rather than sets. I think you're onto something with the Tuple evaluating as True..

Comment: @MaxStackhouse it was just some suggestion, maybe you need tuple in another part of the code, but it should work with your given example. It's really more efficient if you have a big list of words, and if you were looking for performance. Anyway, thanks for the feedback